# Eclipse for PHP official package match alternative syntax keywords

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

I'm using latest Eclipse for PHP official package from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/lunar without error (Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) Build id: 20140612-0600) that ships PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.3.0.201406110111 by default, but I have an issue with PHP alternative syntax highlighting

In a code block I have a foreach loop this way:

```
...
...    
<?php
foreach($things as $thing):
?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $thing; ?>
    </li>    
<?php 
endforeach;
?>
...
...
```

The issue is that Eclipse won't match my code block if I use PHP alternative syntax (foreach -> endforeach match).

It does well if I use standard brackets, it highlight brackets match (for an `if(){ }`, for instance).

Is it possible to have Eclipse PDT to highlight PHP alternative syntax keywords match?

Comment: I am using zend studio 9

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: @zulus, well, I code in my workstation, and using FileSync plugin I keep it synced with the dev server, so no PHP installed in my workstation. In the server I'm using 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3

Comment: I'm asking what php version is set in eclipse settings (Project->Properties->PHP Interpreter). I checked this syntax with PHP 5.5 and everything is working correctly. Also could you tell me what encoding are you using?

Comment: Hi @zulus I'm using UTF-8 and the interpreter set globally is PHP 5.5 with "use short tags" enabled (but I don't use short tag notation in my projects), and that is inherited in the projects as I don't need specific configuration for them...

Answer (score 1):

my eclipse with pdt handles this just fine,

Eclipse SDK

Version: 4.2.2
Build id: M20130204-1200

PHP Development Tools (PDT)   3.1.2.201212211235  org.eclipse.php.feature.group   Eclipse.org

are you properly opening and closing the php blocks,

```
<?php
foreach($tes as $T):
?>



<?php 
endforeach;
?>
```

Update may be that it is broken in (PDT)3.2 or only works in 3.1.2 or such as I have the same PDT build on both of my installations.

Mine also gives me error warnings such as this.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - syntax error, unexpected 'EOF', 
     expecting 'endif'
    - 1 changed line
```

Comment: oh, personally I prefer using good old notepad++ for html but I use a template engine for my html.  Don't ask which one, you've never heard of it I haven't released it yet. :-/

Comment: But did you mean, that you could double click and highlight the block? or just that it picked up the keywords, because I didn't try selecting the block, but it colored both keywords.

Comment: I have Eclipse Version: 4.3.2 Build id: M20140221-1700 and PDT 3.2.0.201306051924 org.eclipse.php.feature.group Eclipse.org. No PHP alternative syntax highlighting happens at all!

Comment: lol, @ downvoted for this.  This is a question that depends a lot on the users setup.  Mine works, in the version I stated above. And in Version: 4.2.0
Build id: I20120608-1400   PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.1.2.201212211235 org.eclipse.php.feature.group Eclipse.org

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, can you edit your answer with detailed steps to get this working with latest Eclipse for PHP?. Official package (Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) Build id: 20140612-0600) eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/lunar Thanks!

Comment: There were no steps mine just works, I don't know what else to say.  I mean I just installed that version like a year or so ago, and I don't typically use the alternative syntax, so I checked when I seen this post and it just worked.  I could tell you how to install eclipse and PDT but there are plenty of guides on that topic already that do a much better job explaining then I could. -- sorry

Comment: You are right, installing PDT is easy and even more if you download the Eclipse PHP package. Will ask the developers for this...